# Many-to-many relationships in EF Core in versions higher than 3. How should they be implemented?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, orm, ef-core-6.0

My current question is about how should a many-to-many relationship be implemented in Entity Core Framework? I've recently started working on a project and I've almost completed the implementation of the database. In the database, I have 2 many-to-many relationships and as you all probably already know a many-to-many relationship implies theoretically creating an auxiliary junction table between the 2 main tables with a one-to-many relationship from each of the 2 main tables to the junction table. All clear till here. However, I've read the explanations in the following 2 links and figured out that when it comes to programatically configuring the relation, depending on the version of Entity Core Framework you may need or may not introduce the junction table. I put the links below:

[many-to-many relationship](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/conventions/many-to-many-relationship)

[many-to-many relationship configuration](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/many-to-many-relationship-configuration)

To conclude, my EF Core version is 6.x and I've already used the junction table approach, even though I've recently found out in versions bigger than 5 you can omit it. The question is if it is safe to keep this approach (maybe backwards compatibility issues) and what way of configuring is better? I think it should be, but thought a question might clarify further the topic.

Comment: Of course it's safe. It's just two 1:n associations. Whether a hidden junction class (or "skip navigation") is better is a question of opinion.